# Ant build error : src does not exist

Tags: ant

I was trying to run my build through Ant tool but console output always shows this error :

```
 **E:\Automation\PowerElectronicsWorkShop\FreesunPortal\build.xml:31: srcdir "E:\Automation\PowerElectronicsWorkShop\FreesunPortal\${src.dir}" does not exist!
```

Build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="" basedir="." default="runTests">
    <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
    <property name="ws.jars" value="E:\Automation\Jar files\Jars"/>
    <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
    <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
    <property name="ng.result" value="test-output" />  

    <presetdef name="javac">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" />
    </presetdef>

    <target name="setClassPath">
        <path id="classpath_jars">
            <fileset dir="E:\Automation\Jar files">
            <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>

            <pathelement path="${class.path}" />

        </path>
        <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars" />
    </target>
    <target name="clean" depends="setClassPath">
        <echo message="deleting existing build directory"/>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <echo message="compiling.........."/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>

    </target>
    <target name="runTests" depends="compile">
        <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>       
        <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${build.dir}">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
        </testng>
    </target>   
</project>
```

I don't understand why this is occurring every time.

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: You didn't inicialize/set "build.dir" and "src.dir" properties in your code

Answer (score 0):

Add Following code under property tag

```
<property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
```

Now you can re build your code through `ANT`, it will work.